# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread while starting wildfly

Tags: java, out-of-memory, server, wildfly

I want to start a wildfly on my virtual server. Every time I run ./wildfly/bin/standalone.sh I get the following error while bootstrapping:

```
MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ironjacamar.idle-remover: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ironjacamar.idle-remover: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.jca.IdleRemoverService.start(IdleRemoverService.java:53)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1357) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:668) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.idle.IdleRemover.start(IdleRemover.java:137)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.jca.IdleRemoverService.start(IdleRemoverService.java:51)
    ... 5 more
```

A `ulimit -a` gets me the following:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 385262
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 385262
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

As you can see, virtual memory is unlimited and max user processes is pretty hugh.
I also increased/decreased the stack size with -Xss256kb when starting the jvm as described [in this post](http://blog.egilh.com/2006/06/2811aspx.html) but without any success.
Also increasing `max-threads` by 50 in standalone.xml for every subsystems did not work (described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582851/4909414)).
Do you have any other idea how to solve this problem?

Java version is

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Try increasing `open files`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15736766/3080094

Comment: how much physical memory is on the box?

Comment: @vanOekel I set it now to 65536 but the error still occurs.

Comment: @John Ament the server has 2gb

Comment: What settings are you passing in when you start wildfly?

Comment: Here are the JAVA_OPTS from from wildfly/bin/standalone.conf: `-Xms64m -Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true` These are the standard values expect -Xmx1500m

Answer (score 1):

To fix `OutOfMemoryError`, launch your java process using `-Xmx2048m` switch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not work as the error message does not point to heap space but to "unable to create new native thread".  I also tried this but the error still occurs.

Comment: Did you try increasing the open files handles as suggested by @vanOkeal? That looks like the last option. You have tried pretty much everything.

Comment: I did. In theory I understand what's happening but practically I have no idea why. On my local dev machine everything works fine with the very same settings for the wildfly.

Answer (score 0):

How many CPUs does your box have? IIRC, some thread pools in wildfly are creating threads in relation to the CPU count, so if you have unusually many CPUs, that might be a problem. Although it says it cannot create new threads it might still be a problem with memory (and not with `max user processes`) because every thread need memory as well.

Otherwise you might try to create a heap dump to find out how many thread are created by wildfly.

Maybe a complete startup log could also provide more information

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The server has just one CPU.I will try to create a heap dump.

Comment: added hint on startup log

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the number of open files allowed. The key to the error is `unable to create new native thread`. On Linux if you execute `ulimit -n 8192` that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems, try increasing vm.max_map_count sysctl value if your system supports a higher value.
Default OS limits on Memory Map counts are generally low - 65530.

On a CentOS or RHEL machine,

**sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=131072**

To make this change permanent,
**echo "vm.max_map_count = 131072" >> /etc/sysctl.conf**